# React native (expo) change locale with i18n-js

Tags: react-native, expo, i18n-js

Using the official documentation for Expo Localization https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization I was able to implement translations. However, switching languages does not take immediate effect.

After changing the language on the Settings screen I return back to the home page and the previous language is still active, even though `i18n.locale` is set to the new language.

This is not the full code, but all the important parts:

**settings.js**

```js
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import i18n from '../localizations/i18n';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Settings = () => {
   const router = useRouter();

   const changeLanguage = async () => {
        try {
            i18n.locale = await AsyncStorage.getItem('settings').language;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error getting language', e);
        }
    };

   ... code

   <Pressable onPress={() => router.back()}>
        <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={50} color="black" />
   </Pressable>

   ... form that triggers `changeLanguage()`
}
```

**localizations/i18n.js**

```js
import { I18n } from "i18n-js";

const i18n = new I18n({
    en: {
        hello: 'Hello',
    },
    de: {
        hello: 'Hallo'
    }
});

i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';

export default i18n;
```

**home.js**

```js
import i18n from "../localizations/i18n";
import { Text} from "react-native";

<Text>{i18n.t('hello')}</Text>

<Text>{i18n.t('hello', {locale: i18n.locale})}</Text> // doesn't work either
```

Should I refresh the i18n somehow? There is no mention in the official documentation.